# List of free TCP ports in C++ without using bind() with port=0

Tags: c++, tcp, ffmpeg, port

I need to create a set of dynamic ffmpeg instances that listens to a port that is available within a C++ program. The ffmpeg instances are created using a command identified as `ffmpeg -i tcp://ip:port?listen ...`, where the port number should be an available free port. Then ffmpeg command is executed using `execv()` within a c++ program.

Therefore, I need to find a free port which is currently available without using `bind()` with `port=0`. As I understand, the `bind()` will bind the port when trying to check if the port is available.

Please let me know if there is a way to implement this within C++.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `bind()` with a port of 0 first yourself, this will automatically bind to a free and unused port. Then, use `getsockname()` to find out which port you were bound to. Then close the socket, and execute your `ffmpeg` listener, pointing it to the port your just closed.

Of course, between the time you close the socket and `ffmpeg` starts up, anything else can come in and grab this port. But that's going to be true no matter how you figure out which port is available.

With a little bit more work, you could make this a more reliable process: go ahead and tell `ffmpeg` to bind to port 0. Assuming it works, after it created its socket you can look in `/proc/<pid>/fd` to find its socket, then look in `/proc/net/tcp` to figure out which port it bound to.